# ReactPlayer full screen not working while onStart

Tags: reactjs

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import ReactPlayer from 'react-player'

    class DailyPass extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        data:{},
        popup: 2,
        review:0
        };
    }



    componentDidMount(){
        let url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/landing/";
        fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
        this.setState ({
            data:data[0]
        })
        })
    }




    makeFullscreen = () => {
        document.getElementById('widget2').dblclick()
    }


    render () {
        return (
                <div>
                    <ReactPlayer
                    youtubeConfig={{ playerVars: { showinfo: 0 } }}
                    url={ this.state.data.url }
                    playing
                    width="100%" height="450px"
                    style={{ display:'block',marginLeft:'auto',marginRight:'auto' }}
                    id="player"
                    onStart = {() => this.makeFullscreen()}
                    controls="true"
                    />
                </div>

        )
    }
    }

    export default DailyPass
```

Here I am using react-player with react to embed the youtube video.
I want to make a video screen as a full screen by default.

so i am calling makeFullscreen() function onStart.

But it is not working.

I checked the documentation for onStart function so that I can make double click to make it full screen but, didn't work.

Please have a look

Comment: any solution to make react-player full screen when video starts?